# unfortunately app has stopped when using ImageView

Tags: java, android

my app always **unfortunately app has stopped** when ever i use any media content like **ImageView** every time i use any imageView its stopped

my app is so basic just tow activities **MainActivity** has only Button when press it it leads me to **SecondActivity** second activity has **ImageView and TextView**

if i delete the ImageView its worked perfectly but when ever i try to use the imageview its stopped :( any ideas ?

activity_secound.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_compass" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static Button btn_med;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener1();

    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener1() {
    btn_med = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_med);
    btn_med.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentMed = new Intent("hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia");
                    startActivity(intentMed);
                }
            }
    );
    }
}
```

errlog

```
08-06 12:28:43.502: W/ApplicationPackageManager(16134): getCSCPackageItemText()
08-06 12:28:43.542: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(16134): Parent view is not a TextView
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): Build Date: 03/28/14 Fri
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): Local Branch: 0328_AU200_patches
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): Remote Branch: 
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): Local Patches: 
08-06 12:28:43.592: I/Adreno-EGL(16134): Reconstruct Branch: 
08-06 12:28:43.622: D/OpenGLRenderer(16134): Enabling debug mode 0
08-06 12:28:45.322: W/ApplicationPackageManager(16134): getCSCPackageItemText()
08-06 12:28:45.332: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(16134): Parent view is not a TextView
08-06 12:28:45.342: D/Switch(16134): mDensity : 480.0
08-06 12:28:45.642: D/dalvikvm(16134): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 33% free 17749K/26256K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
08-06 12:28:45.642: I/dalvikvm-heap(16134): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 370830040-byte allocation
08-06 12:28:45.662: D/dalvikvm(16134): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 15K, 33% free 17733K/26256K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
08-06 12:28:45.662: E/dalvikvm-heap(16134): Out of memory on a 370830040-byte allocation.
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4173eea0 self=0x4163eab0
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134):   | sysTid=16134 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074180436
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134):   | state=R schedstat=( 490381792 58729879 489 ) utm=33 stm=16 core=0
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.662: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3022)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:340)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1978)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia.onCreate(QuranMedia.java:14)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5394)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-06 12:28:45.672: I/dalvikvm(16134):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.672: D/skia(16134): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
08-06 12:28:45.692: D/AndroidRuntime(16134): Shutting down VM
08-06 12:28:45.692: W/dalvikvm(16134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4173dda0)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): Process: hayderhussien.apps.qruan, PID: 16134
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hayderhussien.apps.qruan/hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:340)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1978)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia.onCreate(QuranMedia.java:14)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5394)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    ... 11 more
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    ... 24 more
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3022)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
08-06 12:28:45.692: E/AndroidRuntime(16134):    ... 27 more
```

mysecound activity code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class QuranMedia extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran_media);
    }


}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".QuranMedia"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_quran_media" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

secound activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/img_compass" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Where have you defined `R.id.btn_med`?

Comment: Intent intentMed = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecoundActivity.class);startActivity(intentMed);you have to start the second activity like described

Comment: @sasikumar i've update my post and i put the error log

Comment: @Shaishav in the first activity , my app is simple 2 activity 
,,, the first activity have 1 button when i click it its leads me to the secound activity which have **textview and imageview** if i delete the **imageview** its worked without errors but if i use any imageview its stopped

Comment: Post your code for the second activity (which crashes)

Comment: `import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class QuranMedia extends Activity {
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran_media);
 }

 
}
`

thats all the code for the secondactivity

Comment: Whats at line #48 in `R.layout.activity_quran_media`?

Comment: `R.layout.activity_quran_media` its my secound activity that which have the ImageView

Comment: I understand that but your error log points to that line #. Thats why i needed to know

Comment: @Shaishav i update my post and i put all the files main activity , secound activity which called **activity_quran_media** , **Manifest** , mmm i just dont know why ,, its happens with any app i create , any imageview cause this app stop

Comment: I just saw...you're getting out of memory...is the drawable file OK..? try with another one.

Comment: @Shaishav
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/J7mjNBz.png" height="100">  
mm, i create new app but i dont have the drawable file , i'll create it and try another time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hayderhussien.apps.qruan/hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

this above error cause is your `ImageView` sizes.You are loading the image from drawable folder directly without using **bitmap** image size.so try to use the **bitmap** and resize the image to your app convenient sizes [refere here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and try   to start second `Activity`like describing in bellow.

```
'Intent intentMed = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecoundActivity.class);
startActivity(intentMed);
```

Note:due to the image size problem you have another error `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`
follow the 2 steps to resolve the error.

1. use bitmap to resize the image when loading from drawble folder.
2. try to start next `Activity` as shown in above code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intentMed = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecoundActivity.class);

startActivity(intentMed);
```

Please try this.

Comment: i did it but its not working 
and i was use this for intent
`Intent intentMed = new Intent("hayderhussien.apps.qruan.QuranMedia");
                    startActivity(intentMed);`

and the tow methods didnt worked ,, its work when i remove the ImageView

Comment: please share your stack trace crash report